# Convert date format from d M yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, strtotime

I know that there are million questions on here about converting dates in PHP, but none seems to suit my situation.

I would like to convert an array of dates that looks like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => 1 Dec 2018
   [1] => 2 Dec 2018 
   [2] => 3 Dec 2018 
)
```

...into `yyyy-mm-dd` format. It seems that `strtotime()` cannot convert M to m, even though it should be able to do this....

The original format above is coming from a UI and cannot be changed. I therefore have not choice but to convert it.

Here is what I have:

```
$date // this is the original array, in '1 Dec 2018' format

$formatted_date = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($date); $i++) {
    $formatted_date[] = date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime($date));
}
```

From this, the output is

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 70707070-0101-0101 
    [1] => 70707070-0101-0101
    [2] => 70707070-0101-0101 
)
```

Comment: Try using `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))`

Comment: I knew that it's be something dead simple like that :-)

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius Hmm, it still isn't working. Now I am getting the following as output of my `$formatted_date` : Array ( [0] => 1970-01-01 [1] => 1970-01-01 [2] => 1970-01-01 )

Comment: I guess that this means that my original date is not in a format that `strtotime` can recognise, by why can't it!?

Comment: Please add in your forloop. $formatted_date[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date[$i])); It is working fine.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: Oh I didn't see $date is an array.